# Why does this method fail to make $A_{2x2}$ triangular?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 3 & 5\end{bmatrix}$.

I want to find a rotation matrix P in the form $P = \begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$ such that $P A P^{-1} = P A P^H$ (right?) is upper triangular.

My textbook tells me to put one eigenvector of $A$ into the first row of $P$ and then fill out the next row to make $P$ orthogonal. Thus, one possibility is $P = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, which yields:

$$PA P^H = \begin{bmatrix}2 & -4 \\ 0 & 4\end{bmatrix}$$

I want to approach this problem by instead solving for $\theta$. Since all we care about is getting $A_{11}$ to equal zero, I simply compute the multiplication:

$$\begin{align}
P A P^H & = \begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 3 & 5\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{bmatrix} \\
& = \begin{bmatrix}* & * \\
5\cos^2\theta + 2\sin\theta\cos\theta + \sin^2\theta & *\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$

Plugging $5\cos^2\theta + 2\sin\theta\cos\theta + \sin^2\theta = 0$ into a calculator yields several complex roots:

```
array([-1.33897252-0.40235948j,  1.80262013-0.40235948j,
       -1.33897252+0.40235948j,  1.80262013+0.40235948j])
```

(This is Python output, so `j` means $i$.)

Now, I would expect the 45 degree rotation implied by the textbook's solution to show up here, but if we just roll with it and choose (arbitrarily) the first value above for $\theta$, then we get P =

```
array([[ 0.24860289-0.40224793j,  1.05309876+0.09495786j],
       [-1.05309876-0.09495786j,  0.24860289-0.40224793j]])
```

But $P A P^H$ fails to give us the desired result:

```
array([[ 6.26099034+1.78885438j, -2.68328157+2.68328157j],
       [ 2.68328157-2.68328157j,  1.78885438+1.78885438j]])
```

Two questions:

1. Why does this method fail to produce the $\theta$-values corresponding to the
   the eigenvectors of $A$ that we know make $P A P^H$ triangular?
2. Why don't the $\theta$-values produced by this method work?

---

I *think* the problem might lie in assuming that
$$\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{bmatrix}^H = \begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$$
in the complex case. One bit of evidence for that is that fact that $P P^H \neq I$ if you use the $P$ I calculated above.

But then, what is $\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{bmatrix}^H$ if we admit complex $\theta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either made a mistake in computing the matrix product $PAP^H$ or extracted the wrong element. $5\cos^2\theta+2\cos\theta\sin\theta+\sin^2\theta$ is the lower-right element of that product. You need the lower-left element, which is $3\cos^2\theta-4\cos\theta\sin\theta+\sin^2\theta=\cos2\theta-2\sin2\theta+2$. This has real roots, one of which is the same 45-degree angle that you got using the first method.

Comment: Thank you. You are correct. Do have have any insight into the matter of whether the transpose of a rotation matrix is the same as the Hermitian for complex theta?